# Deleting records from mongodb using jmeter

Tags: mongodb, jmeter

I am trying to delete records in loop using the following code. But it is deleting is only the first record and giving success message for the rest, but its not reflecting in the mongo dB.

```
import com.mongodb.*
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.conversions.Bson;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;

try{
    MongoCollection<Document> collection=vars.getObject("collection");
    Bson filter=eq("empid","${empid}");

    collection.deleteOne(filter); //delete the document

    return"Document deleted";
}
catch(Exception e){
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: "+e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't inline JMeter Variables like `${empid}` into Groovy scripts as given you use compiled scripts caching feature **only first occurrence will be used in subsequent calls**

As per [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:

> Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.

> Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.

> When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as **caching would only cache first replacement. Instead use script parameters.**

So I believe if you change this line:

```
Bson filter = eq("empid", "${empid}");
```

to this one:

```
Bson filter = eq("empid", vars.get("empid"));
```

your code will start working as expected.

In the above snippet `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see JavaDoc for available functions list and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) to learn more about other JMeter API shortcuts available for JSR223 test elements

Comment: It is deleting from one collection but when I am trying to give different collection from the same database, it is not working.